# How do you define a 1-1 relationship bidirectionally with phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon

I have two tables, `work_order` and `project`. On the `project` records, there is a `work_order_id` field. There is no `project_id` on the `work_order` records. Do I need to add one?

Or is there a way to define these relationships using `hasOne/belongsTo`?

I've tried:

```
class WorkOrder extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasOne('id', Project::class, 'work_order_id');
    }
}
```

```
class Project extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasOne('work_order_id', WorkOrder::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

I can retrieve the `WorkOrder` from the project like so: `$project->workOrder`, but I cannot retrieve a `Project` from a `WorkOrder` using `$workOrder->project`. I want a bidirectional relationship.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `hasOne()` relationship in `Project` to a `belongsTo()`?

Comment: @Quasipickle I tried that, yeah. When I looked at the documentation it appeared as though belongsTo is for an n-1 relationship. When I looked up how to do a 1-1 relationship, the documentation just said to use hasOne/hasOne. I did try a belongsTo as well. I couldn't find any documentation on which field is which either for belongsTo. I'm using Phalcon 3.4.

Comment: Is `project`.`work_order_id` unique?  Can multiple projects have the same `work_order_id`?  Admittedly grasping at straws...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the alias parameter, since the implicit retrieval might try to use the class name and it wouldn't support namespaces in your models.

I found it quite bogus in phalcon 1/2/3 to work with hasOne. I've been using belongsTo since then until I re-wrote the pre-post-save part of the phalcon relationship manager for my personal needs. Keep in mind that belongsTo will be saved before the main model you are working with, other types of relationships will be created/updated after the main record is saved. I choose to use "belongsTo" or "hasOne" depending on the order that I want the records and their relationships to be saved.

```
class WorkOrder extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->belongsTo('project_id', Project::class, 'id', ['alias' => 'Project']);
    }
}

class Project extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasOne('id', WorkOrder::class, 'project_id', ['alias' => 'WorkOrder']);
        $this->hasMany('id', WorkOrder::class, 'project_id', ['alias' => 'WorkOrderList']);
    }
}
```

Implicit retrieval should start with a ucfirst camelized string of your class name, or using a get.

```
$workOrder = WorkOrder::findFirst();
$project = $workOrder->Project;
$project = $workOrder->getProject(['deleted <> 1']);

$workOrderList = $project->WorkOrderList;
$workOrder = $project->WorkOrder;
$workOrder = $project->getWorkOrder(['deleted <> 1', 'order' => 'projectId desc']);
```